# How to extract the state, city and country from address

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests
API_KEY = "AIzaSyAeVWl5w9M5JvfCsIUH18435VGHVc"
address = "322 DURANGO DOWNS DR HUTTO, Texas 78634 United States"

parms = {
    'key' : API_KEY,
    'address' : address
}
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
response = requests.get(url,params=parms).json()
print(response)
```

Is there any solution to get city name, country name, zip code and street from the raw string

Comment: Your output is similar to the JSON shown here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding. You could use code like this: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/python-tutorial-google-geocoding-api/

Comment: I need an output like zipcode: 78634, Country: United States, State: Texas, city: hutto

Comment: What does print(response['results']['address_components'][0]) give you?